# Microsoft Office access has stop working error in sql Query

Tags: sql, winforms, ms-access

I tried to merge 3 tables it working fine till adding address column of third table. If i add address column and save or click Data Sheet view suddenly Access table stop working and restarts

[image]
This is my code i working as parameter but if i give correct column name it showing error. Help me to complete my task.

```
SELECT RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms, 
RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote, 
RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, RPT_Customer.CustomerName, 
RPT_Customer.CustomerId, RPT_Customer.ContactPerson, 
RPT_Customer.BillingAddress, RPT_Customer.DeliveryAddress, 
RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy,
RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes, 
RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount, RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, 
RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax, RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyName, 
RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyId, RPT_OrionSystem.RegistrationNumber, 
RPT_OrionSystem.Address1, RPT_OrionSystem.MobileNumber, 
RPT_OrionSystem.FaxNumber, RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyEmail, 
RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyWebsite, RPT_OrionSystem.VatTinNumber

FROM (RPT_Invoice_Less 

INNER JOIN RPT_Customer ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId=RPT_Customer.CustomerId) 
INNER JOIN RPT_OrionSystem ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId=RPT_OrionSystem.CompanyId;
```

In the 10th line `RPT_OrionSystem.Address1` is parameter if I give correct column name `RPT_OrionSystem.Address` MS Access stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys finally I solved myself by removing sub-queries and join sub-queries directly to this query. This code I used

```
SELECT RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms, RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote, RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, 

RPT_Customer.CustomerName, RPT_Customer.CustomerId, RPT_Customer.ContactPerson, RPT_Customer_Address.BillingAddress, RPT_Customer_Address.DeliveryAddress, 

RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes, RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount, RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax, RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, 

RPT_Company.CompanyName, RPT_Company.CompanyId, RPT_Company.RegistrationNumber, RPT_Company_Address.Address, RPT_Company.MobileNumber, RPT_Company.FaxNumber, RPT_Company.CompanyEmail, RPT_Company.CompanyWebsite, RPT_Company.VatTinNumber

FROM (((RPT_Invoice_Less 
INNER JOIN RPT_Customer 
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId=RPT_Customer.CustomerId) 

INNER JOIN RPT_Company 
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId=RPT_Company.CompanyId) 

INNER JOIN RPT_Company_Address 
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId=RPT_Company_Address.AddressId) 

INNER JOIN RPT_Customer_Address 
ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId=RPT_Customer_Address.CustomerId;
```